# Building RethinkDb server in Ubuntu 14.10 results in an error

Tags: ubuntu, rethinkdb

I tried to compile `RethinkDb` from source code following this official [link](http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install/ubuntu/). But running this command

```
sudo make install
```

results in an error at step 7:

```
[7/13] M4 build/release/assets/rethinkdb.1

bin/bash: m4: command was not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the `m4` package. On Ubuntu, you can install it by doing

```
sudo apt-get install m4
```